# How to randomly spawn object using instantiate

Tags: unity, javascript, random

I'm trying to spawn objects which move in one direction until they hit a player or the barrier. The spawner is a cube which moves between two points to spawn the object at different locations.

The code I am using is:

```
#pragma strict
var speed : int = 1;
var direction : int = 1;
var shot : Transform;

var lastSpawn : float;
var nextSpawn : int;

function Update () {
    transform.Translate(Vector3(0, direction * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0));
    if (Time.time > lastSpawn + nextSpawn){
        Instantiate(shot, new Vector3(transform.position.x - 1, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
    }

    lastSpawn = Time.time;  
    nextSpawn = Random.Range(1, 3); 
}
```

All the prefabs and gameObjects are assigned correctly. Should this code work or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure to understand *completely* what is your problem.

Although, `lastSpawn = Time.time` should not be called at every frame but rather when you create a new object. I don't see a reason to have `nextSpawn = Random.Range(1, 3);` out of the braces but that should not be a problem.

```
function Update () 
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3(0, direction * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0));
    if (Time.time > lastSpawn + nextSpawn)
    {
        Instantiate(shot, new Vector3(transform.position.x - 1, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);

        lastSpawn = Time.time;  
        nextSpawn = Random.Range(1, 3); 
    }
}
```